# Binary file download through GSM modem

Tags: parsing, gsm, at-command, modem, bin

I working with a BGS2-W modem. I have a C app writing AT commands to the modem. The responses of the modem look something like \r\n OK or \r\n\n OK. Anytime I receive a \r or a \n, I consider that the end of the modem at response.

Issue is I am attempting to download a binary file through HTTP GET and the binary file can and does contain '\r' and '\n'. This is causing issues when I try to parse the modem responses.

Anyone ever experience this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally most of the modems have a command mode and a data mode (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_and_Data_modes_(modem)). When host sends a command to invoke data mode, modem sends a "CONNECT" response and then you are supposed to interpret data as it is.  Please use the same concept while writing your C code. It's good to write your own code but may I suggest that you find a open source library which takes care of most of this stuff.

Comment: *"When modem wants to use data mode..."* -- It's not up to the modem.  Command versus data (aka transparent) mode is completely under control of the host.  Otherwise your answer is the most informative of the 3 current answers.

Comment: Agreed. Edited the answer accordingly

Comment: How i can check it switch to text mode after data mode completed? MS SerierPort not work well for DTR check.

Answer (score 0):

I found something from [this file](http://hk.elecomes.com/images/upload/File/Datasheet/M1000/BGS2-w_atc_v00100.pdf), page 237, there is a HTTP download example.

When using AT^SISR=4,[reqLength], from 1st line of response there is the **length of data available**. From here, you should use this data length, but not \r or \n as end mark.

From page 208, there is more explanation of ^SISR.

Answer (score 0):

You should not consider \r or \n as a modem answer, since those characters might come as legitimate data exchange both in binary files, ascii files or just the header of an http message.
The AT+RECV or whatever similar command that your modem uses to receive data must have a field that specify the amount of data received, then comes the data and then the OK string.
Focus on parsing the field as a whole, so that you ignore those special characters within the expected data.